# 'Unknown type name FBSDK_EXTERN' Build Error resulting from use of CocoaPods and use_frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to upgrade my iOS app with the latest FacebookSDK. Facebook recommends the use of CocoaPods for upgrades. I was already using another 3rd party SDK that also uses CocoaPods. For the existing 3rd party SDK, it requires the use of use_frameworks! in the podFile. However, when I run 'pod update' and then build my app, I get the following errors:

```
Unknown type name FBSDK_EXTERN [facebook header file]
```

for each Facebook header file that uses this extern. How can I resolve this apparent incompatibility between podFile requirements of these two different SDKs?

My podFile looks like the following:

```
 platform :ios, '8.0'

 def shared_pod
   use_frameworks!

   pod 'apptentive-ios', '~> 4'
   pod 'FacebookSDK'

 end

 target 'myApp' do
   shared_pod
 end

 target 'myOtherApp' do
   shared_pod
 end
```

Alternatively, how can I resolve the 'Unknown type name FBSDK_EXTERN' to allow my app to build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had the same problem.

I believe this can be cause by CocoaPods cache.

The best approach (and worked for me) is

- go to the `/Pods` folder
- delete the problematic framework folder (may be
  named FBSDKLoginKit)
- run `pod install --repo-update` again

if that doesn't work try resolving your pod to the previous version
`pod 'FacebookSDK', '4.37.0'`

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your help. Deleting the framework folders did not help. However, I was able to successfully build by using your suggestion of using the previous version 4.37.0. But I can't upgrade to 4.38.0. Do you have any ideas on what I can do to upgrade to 4.38.0? The need to update is what started this problem. When I upgrade to 4.38, I get these 'Unknown type name FBSDK_EXTERN' errors.

Comment: Actually, I see that Facebook is only warning me to upgrade to 4.37, so perhaps 4.38 is not working yet. So thanks for your help. I've marked it solved.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error when tried to compile FBSDKShareKit 4.38.1 with FacebookSDK 4.37.0. Updating FacebookSDK to 4.38.0 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Francisco's solution without success, downgraded to 4.37.0 and suddenly still got the same error (even though I had this version installed right before trying to update).

What then helped was simply **cleaning Xcode's build folder**, building now works for me.